# Why are creepers afraid of cats?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Once I found out that creepers are afraid of ocelots, I took my pet cat outside and  lead it to a creeper, which immediately ran away. My question is: is there a real reason why creepers are afraid of ocelots?

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. StackExchange is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. This sort of question doesn't really fit the SE format, and might be more suited to such a forum (...though honestly, there's not even really much to discuss; it's a pretty mundane observation).

Comment: After the rewording, it's not an actual question, but still off-topic, as reasons for programmer's decisions are literally unanswerable in most cases.

Comment: gameplay is probably the only reason. It would probably be quite hard to find a solid, objective answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is a part of their inherent behaviour

> Creepers will flee from ocelots and cats if one is too close, until they are approximately 16 blocks away from the feline(s).

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper#Behavior)

This is the same for skeletons that flee from dogs, for example.

There is no real reason why, other than that. But people have used it to their advantage, to make creeper farms, or to set up guards around their bases to protect them from creepers.